# linq to sql upgrade path?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql

I have a .Net Framework library project containing a bunch of models and business logic based off Linq 2 Sql. I currently have a .Net Framework website consuming it. I want to create a new .Net Core Web API and access this library.

What do I upgrade this library to that will allow it to be consumed by both .Net Framework and .Net core? Is there a ".Net Standard Entity Framework?" I can only see .Net Core EF. So I am at a loss as to how to share this logic layer with my old .net framework and new .net core website.

Answer (score 0):

EF 6.3 runs on .net standard and compatible with Framework and Core.